# How to use azure-ad-b2c to customize the html and css of the login page

Tags: azure, user-interface

According to the document https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview, I can use  to introduce ad b2c users I want to add other content in , such as an input box for inputting other information. How should I do it?

Comment: its a good idea to perhaps post, steps, that you might have already tried and where you got stuck with code and related examples.

Comment: Can you provide me with some code or examples on this issue?